# Binding closing of toplevel window

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

How can I create a binding in tkinter for when someone closes a toplevel window or if it is closed with `toplevel1.destroy()` or something similar. I am trying to make a small pop-up and when the user closes the main window or toplevel I want to prompt the user to save a file. I have figured out that I can set the actual close button to the function but cannot figure out how to get .destroy() and the closing of the main window to call the function. What should I do to bind the destroy function or window closing function?

Tested code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
class TestWidget(tk.toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)

    def close(self):
        print("Closed")
        self.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    TestWidget()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"but can't do this with toplevels for some reason."_ - please show what you've tried. There's no technical reason why this can't be done.

Comment: `"WM_DELETE_WINDOW"` is used in conjunction with the `.protocol()` method, *not* `.bind()`.

Comment: @jasonharper that fixed the bind for when I delete the window directly. How can I call the close function when the main window is destroyed and when `test.destroy` is called?

Comment: I updated my problem

Comment: It is better to raise another question instead of changing original question to another question.

Comment: @acw1668 I wasn't changing the question but rather focusing on other aspects of the problem I had initially addressed

Comment: I found a solution to the problem through the `.winfo_children()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that if you make a toplevel widget integrated into a class that you can find all the classes with the code below:

```py
for child in root.winfo_children():
        print(child)
```

This returns all the widgets and classes used:

```
.!testwidget
.!testwidget2
```

With this I can set up a function in the main window to call the child's close function one by one and this allows me to gain access to all the needed pieces